# Adding content to a class selector inside a div that is inside a <li>

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-selectors

How can I add content to one of the paragraph of class `error_descr` below?

```
<li id="list_item-1">
     <div>
          <p class="error_descr"></p>
     </div>
</li>
<li id="list_item-2">
     <div>
          <p class="error_descr"></p>
     </div>
</li>
<li id="list_item-3">
     <div>
          <p class="error_descr"></p>
     </div>
</li>
```

What I tried is `jQuery('#list_item-2 div p.error_descr').html("Mising something...");` but it's not working. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Why are you using ids like that? Are you sure that there aren't any other `li`s with the same id (e.g. within a different list)? Without seeing the rest of your code, I can't be sure, but I suspect that could be the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the LI elements have parent tags?  That's the only thing I can see that looks odd, but your code should still work.  You can see a working example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/vgcv6/1/

Basically there is nothing wrong with your code.  If you are experiencing problems they probably exist somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

try `$('#list_item-2 div').children('p.error_descr').html('Mising something...');`

edit:
add div on parent selector

Comment: I think `.children()` returns the *immediate* children; since the `p` tags are inside `div` tags that are inside the items, I don't think your code would work. Try `.find()` instead of `.children()`.